# How to write a below query in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I write the below SQL query in Neo4j Cypher?

```
SELECT t1.EmpNo, 
       t1.LastName, 
       t1.BirthDate, 
       t2.EmpNo, 
       t2.LastName, 
       t2.Birthdate
FROM Employee t1, Employee t2
WHERE t1.BirthDate = t2.Birthdate
AND t1.EmpNo <> t2.EmpNo
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your model really but the most equivalent form would probably be :

```
MATCH(t1:Employee),(t2:Employee)
WHERE t1.BirthDate = t2.BirthDate
AND t1.EmpNo <> t2.EmpNo
RETURN t1.EmpNo, t1.LastName, t1.BirthDate, t2.EmpNo, t2.LastName, t2.Birthdate
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom